# Hacer un insert dentro de un bucle While

Tags: php

Se pasa la data de la tabla **Origen** a la tabla **Proceso** con la siguiente clase:

```
$stmt = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO proceso (cod, nom, cant)
    SELECT cod, nom, cantidad
    FROM origen
    WHERE lote = :lote");
$stmt->bindParam('lote', $lote, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Pero por diseño se quiere agregar un campo que sea correlativo (No Autoincremental).

Traté de hacer algo así, pero no sé cómo utilizar el **While** para que procese el **Where**. La clase es:

```
public function insertar($id, $lote) {
    while ((   ) !== FALSE) {
        $stmt = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO proceso (id, cod, nom, cant)
            SELECT :id, cod, nom, cantidad
            FROM origen
            WHERE lote = :lote");
        $id++;
        $stmt->bindParam('id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam('lote', $lote, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

No sé si el **:id** esté bien así, o si mi enfoque es el correcto.

Comment: Así como lo presentas parece bien escrito. Sólo falta la iniciación de `$id` (en que valor inicia cada vez que inicie el bucle). Te sugiero probar el `while` y si tienes problemas o no funciona como quieres, nos lo comentas.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta. No sé cómo condicionar el __while__

Comment: no sabes cuando cortar el while? y.. cuando termines las inserciones.. como sabes cuantas inserciones tenes?

Comment: Insertará los registros que encuentre el where del Select de tabla Origen

Comment: Por tu código, parece ser que `$lote` es la clave para condicionar tu `while`. ¿De dónde sale ese valor en cada iteración del `while`? Eso es tal vez lo que debieras preguntarte. Si quieres recorrer todos los "lote" de tu tabla `origen`, entonces ese es el bucle que debes recorrer.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta, el $lote y el $id vienen con valores a la clase. Pero igual no sé cómo limitar al while

Comment: Mmm según lo veo, tu while debiera ir por fuera de tu método. O sea, hacer el while y dentro llamar al método `insertar`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más sencillo y dado que es una migración de datos (algo que intuyo que se va a hacer una vez o dos) es obtener los datos desde la tabla `origen` y luego insertarlos con un bucle `foreach`

```
public function insertar($id, $lote)
{
    // FIXME: La parte de obtención de datos debería
    //        ir en un método privado para no mezclar responsabilidades…
    $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT
    cod,
    nom,
    cantidad
FROM
    origen
WHERE
    lote = :lote;
SQL;

    $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam('lote', $lote, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $origenRows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    // Al iterar tienes que tener en cuenta la configuración de tu conexión
    // PDO por si devuelve arrays u objetos en los SELECTS
    foreach ($origenRows as $row) {
        $sql = <<<SQL
INSERT INTO proceso
(
    id,
    cod,
    nom,
    cant
) VALUES (
    :id,
    :cod,
    :nom,
    :cantidad
);
SQL;

        $stmt->bindParam('id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam('cod', $row['cod'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam('nom', $row['nom'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('cantidad', $row['cantidad'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $id++;
    }
}
```

Comment: A qué te refieres cuando dices que "la obtención de datos debe ir en un método privado para no mezclar responsabilidades"?

Comment: Me refiero a que tu método se llama "insertar" por lo que, el hecho de que también obtenga datos, estaría infringiendo el principio de responsabilidad única ya que estaría haciendo dos cosas: obtener datos e insertar datos.

Comment: Tomando en consideración lo mencionado tuve que crear dos clases una donde obtengo los registros a trabajar y otra donde los inserto.

Comment: Tomando esta respuesta como la acertada, se podría incluso reducir aun más el trabajo, al hacer el INSERT con el SELECT en una sola consulta SQL (`insert into tabla1 select campos from tabla2 where...`), así se mantendría la diferenciación que menciona @kerunaru : que el método sólo sea de "insertar", no de "seleccionar e insertar". ([Documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html))